# Error Angularjs 1.6 con uibDatepicker usando en el template de un componente

Tags: angularjs

Obtengo el siguiente error con Angularjs 1.6 y con el datepicker de ui-bootstrap:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel',
required by directive 'uibDatepicker', can't be found!
```

Este error aparece sólo cuando uso el datepicker en un componente. Si lo uso en una directiva funciona bien.
El error salta cuando se abre el calendario.

¿Alguna ayuda?
Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que asignarle el atributo [`ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) al elemento donde tienes definido la directiva `ubiDatepicker`.

Probablemente tienes algo como:

```
<div ubiDatepicker></div>
```

Para solucionar el error tienes agregar el `ng-model`:

```
<div ubiDatepicker ng-model="miModelo"></div>
```

Tener en cuenta que la documentacion dice que el **modelo debe de ser un objeto `Date` no un string** para que funcione.